# Using djangoTemplate and db.Model in Google App Engine

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I have a small app that has a form that grabs data about a new hire, emails people about it, and stores the data for future use. Everything is working fine, but I can't seem to find info on using djangoforms and check boxes. These are obviously a boolean value, but if I add a db.Boolean value to my db.Model class, and then had it to djangoforms.ModelForm class to generate it, nothing appears. I added it to my db>model, it creates a record default to false, but there is no way to modify from the form. Also,db.Text doesn't produce a fiel either. I am probably not being clear enough here, due to the fact this is my first GAE and Django project. Code is below

```
import cgi
import wsgiref.handlers
from google.appengine.api import users
from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template
from google.appengine.api import mail
from google.appengine.ext.db import djangoforms

class Item(db.Model):
  first_name = db.StringProperty()
  last_name = db.StringProperty()
  goes_by = db.StringProperty()
  Studio = db.StringProperty()
  Discipline = db.StringProperty()
  position = db.StringProperty()
  level = db.StringProperty(default='choice', choices=['choice', 'choice',
                                                          'choice', 'choice', 'choice', 'choice'])
  start_date = db.DateTimeProperty()
  buddy_name = db.StringProperty()
  past_employee = bool()
  email = db.EmailProperty()
  cell_phone = db.PhoneNumberProperty()
  phone = db.PhoneNumberProperty()
  hire_type = db.StringProperty(default='Full Time',choices=[
    'Temp', 'Intern', 'Contract', 'Full Time'])
  seating_location = db.StringProperty()
  additional_comments = db.Text()
  entry_time = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
  added_by = db.UserProperty()

class ItemForm(djangoforms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Item
    exclude = ['added_by']

class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    self.response.out.write('<html><body><head><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/form.css"></head>'
                            '<div id=header><div id="logo><img src="/img/placeimg.gif"></div><div id ="headertxt"><h2>Place New Hire Portal</h2>'
                            '<p>Please filll out this form as accurately as possible, this information is used to create employee files and to setup IS equipment</div> '
                            '</div><div id="contain">'
                            '<form method="POST" '
                            'action="/">'
                            '<table>')
    # This generates our fields and writes it in the response
    self.response.out.write(ItemForm())
    self.response.out.write('</table>'
                            '<input type="submit">'
                            '</form></div></body></html>')


  def post(self):
    data = ItemForm(data=self.request.POST)
    if data.is_valid():
      # Save the data, and redirect to the view page
      entity = data.save(commit=False)
      entity.added_by = users.get_current_user()
      entity.put()
      self.redirect('/items.html')
      mailing_address = ("person@place.com")
      sender_address = ("person@place.com")
      subject = "A new hire has been made - Please begin Process"
      body = ("""
            The Following Person is scheduled to start at place on :

        %s %s - %s \ %s - %s - %s

        Please find the orientation template attached. In order to be sure all employees are oriented in the same way
        please be sure to cover the items listed under your name.

        In addition, afer the completion of your session, please escort the new hire to the next session and makle introductions. This will
        ensure that the schedule continues in order.

        Buddy, thank you very much for being a buddy to %s, Your time and lunch expenses should be charged to your Studio Operations number. Thank you
        very much for helping %s with their transiton to Place."""

                %(entity.first_name, entity.last_name, entity.Studio, entity.Discipline, entity.seating_location,
                entity.buddy_name, entity.first_name, entity.first_name))

      mail.send_mail(sender_address, mailing_address, subject, body)
    else:
      # Reprint the form
      self.response.out.write('<html><body>'
                              '<form method="POST" '
                              'action="/">'
                              '<table>')
      self.response.out.write(data)
      self.response.out.write('</table>'
                              '<input type="submit">'
                              '</form></body></html>')






class ItemPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    self.response.out.write('</br></br><a href="/">Return to Form Entry</a></br></br>')
    query = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Item ORDER BY first_name")
    for item in query:
      self.response.out.write('<a href="/edit?id=%d">Edit</a> - ' %
                              item.key().id())
      self.response.out.write("%s | %s | %s | %s | %s | %s | %s | %s | %s | %s | %s | %s | %s | %s | %s </br>"%
                              (item.first_name, item.last_name, item.goes_by, item.Studio, item.Discipline, item.position,
                               item.level, item.start_date, item.past_employee, item.cell_phone, item.seating_location,
                               item.additional_comments, item.email, item.phone, item.hire_type))

class EditPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    id = int(self.request.get('id'))
    item = Item.get(db.Key.from_path('Item', id))
    self.response.out.write('<html><body>'
                            '<form method="POST" '
                            'action="/edit">'
                            '<table>')
    self.response.out.write(ItemForm(instance=item))
    self.response.out.write('</table>'
                            '<input type="hidden" name="_id" value="%s">'
                            '<input type="submit">'
                            '</form></body></html>' % id)

  def post(self):
    id = int(self.request.get('_id'))
    item = Item.get(db.Key.from_path('Item', id))
    data = ItemForm(data=self.request.POST, instance=item)
    if data.is_valid():
      # Save the data, and redirect to the view page
      entity = data.save(commit=False)
      entity.added_by = users.get_current_user()
      entity.put()
      self.redirect('/items.html')
    else:
      # Reprint the form
      self.response.out.write('<html><body>'
                              '<form method="POST" '
                              'action="/edit">'
                              '<table>')
      self.response.out.write(data)
      self.response.out.write('</table>'
                              '<input type="hidden" name="_id" value="%s">'
                              '<input type="submit">'
                              '</form></body></html>' % id)



def main():
  application = webapp.WSGIApplication(
                                       [('/', MainPage),
                                        ('/edit', EditPage),
                                        ('/items.html', ItemPage),
                                        ],
                                       debug=True)

  wsgiref.handlers.CGIHandler().run(application)

if __name__=="__main__":
  main()
```

Comment: should be `TextProperty` and `BooleanProperty`. `db.Text` is just an alias to `datastore_types.Text`, not a `Property` subclass, and `db.Boolean` should raise an exception as far as I can see.

Comment: Thank you @Wooble db.Boolean did, but bool() did not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wobble answered it for me

should be TextProperty and BooleanProperty. db.Text is just an alias to datastore_types.Text, not a Property subclass, and db.Boolean should raise an exception as far as I can see